# NextAuth session returning null data in production after successful authentication

Tags: authentication, heroku, next.js, next-auth

I'm just having trouble implementing nextAuth custom credentials provider into my e-commerce app, it was working nice in my localhost, but as soon as i deployed it on the heroku, all suddenly has crashed though im pretty sure nothing is wrong with my config in route APIs.

Tried logging out in console(localhost) as well and shows all those data returned by server in session perfectly just to be able to see whats im really getting from the session, well, so far so good.. but i dont really get why this happens only in production...

So logged-in users cant see both profile pic and email/username on the navbar, showing only default avatar which shows up to the unauthenticated users only...

production link: https://lunarshop.herokuapp.com/

**api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import User from '../../../models/User'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import joi from 'joi'
import {connectDB, disconnect} from '../../../utils/db'
import {MongoDBAdapter} from '@next-auth/mongodb-adapter'
import clientPromise from './lib/mongodb'

import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'


dotenv.config()


 const loginSchema = joi.object({
  email: joi.string().email().required(),
  password: joi.string().min(6).required(),

});



export default NextAuth({
     adapter : MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
     name : 'Sign in',
      credentials : {
        email: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "********" }
      },

      async authorize(credentials,req) {

        let user = null;
        try {
          await connectDB()

          const email = credentials.email
          const password = credentials.password

          console.log(email, password)

          if (!email || !password) {
            throw new Error('Please provide an email and password.');
          }

          const { error } = loginSchema.validate({ email, password })
          if (error) {
            throw new Error(error.details[0].message);
          }

          user = await User.findOne({ email })

          if (!user) {
            throw new Error('Invalid email or password.');
          }

          const checkMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

          if (!checkMatch) {
            throw new Error('Invalid email or password.');
          }

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          throw new Error(error.message);

        } finally {
          await disconnect();
        }
        return user
      }
      
      }),
 
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,

    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: "Iv1.2a94b24ea5010c98",
      clientSecret: "71ff167e340484f06b9e03ff73bb64e4e667f8cb",
    }),
    
  
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
  },

  callbacks: {
    async session({session, token}) {
    
      
      let user = await User.findById(token.sub);
     
      session.user.id = token.sub || user?._id?.toString();
      session.user.role = user?.role || 'user'; 

      console.log(session)     
      return session;
    },

  },


 

    session: {
     
    strategy: 'jwt',


    },
    jwt: {
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,

    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,




})
```

and here is the top bar where the logged-in users' own profile data returned from session will be shown:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import UserMenu from "./UserMenu";
import avatar from "../../public/avatar.png";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
 
function Top() {

  

  const [userMenuVisible, setUserMenuVisible] = useState(false);
  const { data: session} = useSession();


  return (
    <> 
      <div className={styles.top}>
        <div className={styles.top__container}>
          <div></div>

          <ul className={styles.top__list}>
            <li className={styles.li}>

              
              <Image
                src="/heart.svg"
                width={20}
                height={20}
                alt="heart"
                className={styles.test}
              />
              <Link href="/profile/wishlist">
                <span>Wishlist</span>
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li className={styles.li}>
              <span className={styles.cart}>3</span>
              <Image src="/cart.svg" width={22} height={22} alt="cart" />

              <Link href="/cart">
                <span>Cart</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
           

            <li
              className={styles.li}
              onMouseMove={() => setUserMenuVisible(true)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setUserMenuVisible(false)}
            >

                

              {session ? (
                <li className={styles.li}>
                  <div className={styles.flex}>
                    
                    <Image
                      src={session.user.image || avatar}
                      width={64}
                      height={64}
                      alt="avatar"
                    />
                    <span>{session.user.name}</span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              ) : (
                <li className={styles.li}>
                  <div className={styles.flex}>
                    <span>Account</span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              )}
              {userMenuVisible && <UserMenu session={session} />}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Top;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const session = await getSession(context);

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}
```